# How do I cite royal names with their titles in MLA?

Tags: citations, mla

For example, how would I reference *Elizabeth-Charlotte of Bavaria, Princess Palatine, Duchess of Orleans* (all being one single person and their attributes)?

Is there a common practice for royal names in modern language or is that just a thing of the past?

Comment: Citations are more on-topic on [Writers.SE]. However, don't you cite the author as the name actually appears on their publication? If the princess appears as "Elizabeth Hochwald" using a [possibly adopted] family name, then don't you use that?

Comment: Well if her name is Elizabeth-Charlotte of Bavaria, she will appear as "Bavaria, Elizabeth-Charlotte of". That just looks a bit stupid in my opinion, and is also misleading because she does/did not at all live in Bavaria.

Comment: But "Bavaria" is not the surname. If she doesn't have a surname, then what? I reckon it's "Elizabeth-Charlotte of Bavaria", but there are a number of different opinions expressed in a [relevant question on Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46983).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the correct form of the name of a historic person can be difficult and might involve some research. I am no expert, but in the case of your example the German National Library lists her publications under the name [Orléans, Elisabeth Charlotte d'](https://portal.dnb.de/opac.htm?method=simpleSearch&cqlMode=true&reset=true&referrerPosition=0&query=idn%3D118529935), the Libary of Congress lists her as [Orléans, Charlotte-Elisabeth, duchesse d', 1652-1722](https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/search?searchArg=Orle%CC%81ans,%20Charlotte-Elisabeth,%20duchesse%20d%27,%201652-1722.&searchCode=NAME%2B&searchType=1&recCount=25), and the Bibliothèque nationale de France as [Orléans, Charlotte Elisabeth de Bavière (1652-1722 ; duchesse d')](http://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb11918198t).

Comment: Thank you very much. So the approach in general is to look for references citing that person.